# Return NaN - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Good evening, have a question. I am starting to use react making a project with sponacular api. I have this code:

```js
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import ListGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { CartContext } from '../../CartContex/CartContext';
import "./CartOrden.css";


const CartOrden =()=>{
    const {pedidoVegano, pedidoNoVegano, removeItem } = useContext(CartContext);
    
    let totalPrecio = 0;
    let tiempoEspera = 0;
    let healthScore = 0;

    const sumarTotal =(i)=>{
        totalPrecio += i.pricePerServing;
        console.log(totalPrecio)
        
    }

    const calculoEspera =(i)=>{
        tiempoEspera += parseInt(i.readyInMinutes);
        console.log(tiempoEspera)
    }

    const totalHealth = (i)=>{
        healthScore += i.healthScore;
        console.log(healthScore)
    }

        return (
                <Container>
                    <div>
                        <h2>Vegan Menu</h2>
                    </div>

                    <Row className='m-3'>
                        {pedidoVegano.map((i=>{
                           sumarTotal(i.item)
                           calculoEspera(i.item)
                           totalHealth(i.item)
                            return(
                                <Card className='card-first' style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                                    <Card.Img className='card-img' variant="top" src={i.item.image} />
                                    <Card.Body>
                                        <Card.Title className='card-title'>{i.item.title}</Card.Title>
                                        <div className='contain-value'>
                                            <p className='text'><i className="fa-solid fa-dollar-sign"></i> {i.item.pricePerServing}</p> 
                                            <p className='text'><i className="fa-solid fa-heart"></i> {i.item.healthScore}</p> 
                                            <p className='text'><i class="fa-solid fa-clock"></i> {i.item.readyInMinutes}</p> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <Button onClick={()=> removeItem(i.item)}  variant="danger"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i> Delete</Button>
                                        </div>
                                    </Card.Body>
                                </Card>
                            )
                        }))}
                    </Row>  

                    <div>
                        <h2>Vegan't Menu</h2>
                    </div>

                    <Row className='m-3'>
                        {pedidoNoVegano.map((i=>{
                            sumarTotal(i.item)
                            calculoEspera(i.item)
                            totalHealth(i.item)
                            return(
                                <Card className='card-first' style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                                    <Card.Img className='card-img' variant="top" src={i.item.image}  />
                                    <Card.Body>
                                        <Card.Title>{i.item.title}</Card.Title>
                                        <div className='contain-value'>
                                            <p className='text'><i className="fa-solid fa-dollar-sign"></i> {i.item.pricePerServing}</p> 
                                            <p className='text'><i className="fa-solid fa-heart"></i> {i.item.healthScore}</p> 
                                            <p className='text'><i class="fa-solid fa-clock"></i> {i.item.readyInMinutes}</p> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <Button onClick={()=> removeItem(i.item)}  variant="danger"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i> Delete</Button>
                                        </div>
                                    </Card.Body>
                                </Card>
                            )
                        }))} 

                    </Row>

                    <Row className='m-3'>
                        <Card>
                            <Card.Header as="h5">Current Menu</Card.Header>
                            <Card.Body>
                                <Card.Title>Total price: {totalPrecio}</Card.Title>
                                <Card.Title>Total health score: {healthScore} </Card.Title>
                                <Card.Title>Total preparation time: {tiempoEspera} minutes </Card.Title>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    </Row>
                    
                </Container>
    )
}

export default CartOrden;
```

I wanted to unstructure the previous code, to make it more complex and work with components, as it should.

```js
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { CartContext } from '../../CartContex/CartContext';
import "./CartOrden.css";


const CartOrden =({i})=>{

    const { removeItem } = useContext(CartContext);
     
                            return(
                                <Card className='card-first' style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                                    <Card.Img className='card-img' variant="top" src={i.item.image} />
                                    <Card.Body>
                                        <Card.Title className='card-title'>{i.item.title}</Card.Title>
                                        <div className='contain-value'>
                                            <p className='text'><i className="fa-solid fa-dollar-sign"></i> {i.item.pricePerServing}</p> 
                                            <p className='text'><i className="fa-solid fa-heart"></i> {i.item.healthScore}</p> 
                                            <p className='text'><i class="fa-solid fa-clock"></i> {i.item.readyInMinutes}</p> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <Button onClick={()=> removeItem(i.item)}  variant="danger"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i> Delete</Button>
                                        </div>
                                    </Card.Body>
                                </Card>
                            )
    
}

export default CartOrden;
```

```js
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { CartContext } from '../../CartContex/CartContext';
import CartOrden from '../CartOrden/CartOrden';



const ResultOrden =()=>{
    const {pedidoVegano, pedidoNoVegano, } = useContext(CartContext);
    
    let totalPrecio = 0;
    let tiempoEspera = 0;
    let healthScore = 0;

    const sumarTotal =(i)=>{
        totalPrecio += i.pricePerServing;
        console.log(totalPrecio)
        
    }

    const calculoEspera =(i)=>{
        tiempoEspera += parseInt(i.readyInMinutes);
        console.log(tiempoEspera)
    }

    const totalHealth = (i)=>{
        healthScore += i.healthScore;
        console.log(healthScore)
    }

        return (
                <Container>
                    <div>
                        <h2>Vegan Menu</h2>
                    </div>

                    <Row className='m-3'>
                        {pedidoVegano.map((i=>{
                           sumarTotal(i)
                           calculoEspera(i)
                           totalHealth(i)
                            return(
                                <CartOrden i={i} key={i.pricePerServing}/>
                            )
                        }))}
                    </Row>  

                    <div>
                        <h2>Vegan't Menu</h2>
                    </div>

                    <Row className='m-3'>
                        {pedidoNoVegano.map((i=>{
                            sumarTotal(i)
                            calculoEspera(i)
                            totalHealth(i)
                            return(
                                <CartOrden i={i} key={i.id}/>
                            )
                        }))} 

                    </Row>

                    <Row className='m-3'>
                        <Card>
                            <Card.Header as="h5">Current Menu</Card.Header>
                            <Card.Body>
                                <Card.Title>Total price: {totalPrecio}</Card.Title>
                                <Card.Title>Total health score: {healthScore} </Card.Title>
                                <Card.Title>Total preparation time: {tiempoEspera} minutes </Card.Title>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    </Row>
                    
                </Container>
    )
}

export default ResultOrden;
```

I wanted to know why in the first case the code works but in the second within ResultOrden, the healthScore, tiempoEspera and totalPrice returns NaN.

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vu5U.png)

Sorry if the question is basic, I was trying to solve it and I couldn't. I'm probably missing something about communication between components but couldn't find it. If anyone can give me some advice, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What has in this i, in the pedidoNoVegano context? Sometimes you use i.item, and in the last code  you acces just i.property. Isn't it i.item.property?

Comment: Also, i recommend you use the useState. For example, let [totalPrecio, setPrecio] = useState(0). And after that you just, setPrecio(number + totalPrecio). But you need to learn about this hook.